# Are GPU's limited in their ability to do larger calculations?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, cuda, hardware, gpu

Sorry about the vague title.

I wrote a kernel to do some simulations with 3D heat transfer. The problem I am having is that the version of my program running parallel on an 8-core Dell Studio XPS outpaces my GTS-240 GPU. I have tried many things to try to get it to run faster, but I have come to the conclusion that it is just the calculation itself that is too large. The calculation has about 35 FLOP and I simply launch a thread for each cell in the simulation. Still, I only get about 33.4 million cells/second on the GPU and 40.4 mllion/sec on the CPU. It was my understanding that GPU's excelled at tasks like this, where there are 1.7 million cells per time step that each need this calculation done on them.

I also have 28 array accesses per calculation, all in normal GPU memory.

Here is the calculation. I won't post the real thing - not that it's top secret, it's just unnecessary. Variables prefixed with "f" are floating point numbers and "i" means integer.

```
f_celldata[iA] =(-f_constA[iA-iB] * (f_mutA[iA] - f_mutA[iA-iB]) / f_constB[iA-1] + 
                  f_constA[iA]    * (f_mutA[iA+iB] - f_mutA[iA]) / f_constB[iA]) * (1.0 / f_constB[iA]) + 
                 (-f_constA[iA-iC] * (f_mutA[iA] - f_mutA[iA-iC]) / f_constB[iA-1] + 
                   f_mutA[iA] * (f_constA[iA+*iC] - kern_T_mat[linOffset]) / kern_dy_e[y]) * (1.0  /kern_dy_c[y]) + 
                  (-f_constA[iA-1] * (f_mutA[iA] - f_mutA[iA-1]) / f_constB[iA-1] + 
                    f_constA[iA] * (f_mutA[iA+1] - f_mutA[iA]) / f_constB[iA]) * (1.0 / f_constB[iA]);
```

Obviously I went kinda sloppy when I wrote this down here. In reality the calculation is as simple as it can be, and there are a lot more variables that, here, I made the same for simplicity.

I was hoping that people more experienced with GPU programming than I could give me some advice. Is the calculation too large to do with a GPU? The single calculation alone (the array accesses and FLOP together) take 35 ms per time step. Is this more or less typical? I don't really see how I can make it any faster. Would the job go much faster with a Tesla? How much faster about?

Thank you.

Comment: The GTS-240 is a three year old, mid-performing GPU. It has about 1/10th of the peak performance of a current state-of-the-art GPU. You need to keep that in mind...

Comment: The answer to your question is "no".  The size of a calculation has nothing to do with the suitability of GPUs for the problem.  And there's no such thing as a typical answer for an unspecified problem with unspecified storage.  But you can break your own problem down and see how close to theoretical peak you are in terms of memory bandwidth, ops / s, etc.  If you want more advice on improving the performance, post a different question with more detail.

Comment: "not that it's top secret, it's just unnecessary" Well, I wouldn't be so sure about that. Are you sure you're getting the memory accesses right? That's not exactly trivial in Cuda.

Comment: What's the FLOP peak for that GPU? What's the memory bandwidth peak for that GPU? How many flops are you doing for each point, and how many bytes of memory are you accessing?

Answer (score 2):

No, GPUs are not limited in their ability to do larger calculations.

It is hard to be sure without seeing the actual code. The only thing that is obviously wrong with the sample you provided is the 1.0/x part. "1.0" is double-precision, and double-precision floating point performance of NVIDIA GPUs is much lower than single-precision. Besides, it shouldn't even compile on your GTS 240, because it is compute capability 1.1 and it does not have double-precision support at all.

In any case, the performance you see is almost certainly due to a global memory bottleneck. The 200-series did not have great caching capabilities and you had to take special measures to optimize memory accesses. (This is partially true for newer GPUs, but to a lesser extent.) You need to understand the memory access pattern of your code and minimize global memory accesses.

Answer (score 0):

There is a memory hierarchy on the GPU. You want to make sure your memory accesses are as fast as possible as it seems that your IO bandwidth is the bottleneck.

You might want to look into texture memory for improved spatial locality and caching.

[image]

Comment: I like that you included a memory diagram, but I think this particular diagram might be more misleading than helpful. It shows a conceptual overview of what might be an older architecture. It does not show how the memory spaces are implemented and so does not give any clues as to the latencies. In particular, it makes it look as if Local Memory is as fast as Shared Memory. It also does show the Constant and Texture caches, or the L1 and L2 caches available in newer architectures.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Fermi Memory Architecture]

As an alternative to the memory diagram that @tskuzzy posted, I grabbed this from the Nsight profiler. It shows an overview of the memory architecture on Fermi, including which memory space backs each type of instruction (the row closest to the kernel).

Answer (score 0):

GPUs do some things really well, and some things really badly. The trick is to write you code to exploit what they do well and do as little as possible of the stuff they do badly.

I suspect, but it's impossible to tell as you didn't supply any code, that your bottle neck is nothing to do with the speed of the GPU doing the calculation. It'll be one of the following:

- You're spending most of your time moving data to/from the GPU.

  - i.e. your kernel is simple, takes almost no time to execute, but loading source data, and getting results back takes the time.
  - GPUs love having lots of work to do on a single data set.
- You're making the GPU work synchronously with the CPU, and you're CPU limited.

  - If you have a CPU loop which waits for the GPU to finish, prepares the next set of work, and then kicks off the GPU again, it's very easy to get bottle-necked on the CPU. Better to use the time that the GPU is working to prepare the next set of work for the GPU, rather than just waiting.
- You're not asking for enough parallel threads to do the work.

  - A GPU is fast because it can run hundreds of threads. Not because one thread is fast (it's not).
  - If you can't exploit this, there's no point.
- You're using a slow type of memory to store your variables.

  - GPUs have various memory types that have various access speeds. Small, Local and fast; Large, Global but slow.
  - Frequently accessed variables want to be in as fast memory as is possible.

Possibly surprisingly, it's not likely to be the kernel, but the host code which will show a lot of the issues, and the code does matter.